# Increase power on USB port to 2A on Manjaro Linux

Tags: linux, usb, iphone, charging, manjaro

I want to charge my Apple iPhone SE (the old one) with my Laptop Huawei Matebook D with Manjaro Linux installed on. I was already able to increase to power from 100mA to 500mA using `tlp`. Now the phone charges, but really slow. I know that the Motherboard/BIOS is able to provide 2A (1.8A) to this port, as it has worked with the preinstalled Windows. Is there any way to increase the current on the specific USB port?

I already tried to use `ipad_charge` even with explicit bus and device specifications, but I only get:
`ipad_charge: no such device or an error occured`

Current kernel version: 5.8.18-1
Manjaro version: 20.2
iOS version: 14.2
Output of `lsusb -v |grep 'Bus\|MaxPower'`:

```
Couldn't open device, some information will be missing
Couldn't open device, some information will be missing
Bus 004 Device 001: ID 1d6b:0003 Linux Foundation 3.0 root hub
    MaxPower                0mA
Bus 003 Device 002: ID 0408:1020 Quanta Computer, Inc. hm1091_techfront
      (Bus Powered)
    MaxPower              500mA
Couldn't open device, some information will be missing
Couldn't open device, some information will be missing
Bus 003 Device 001: ID 1d6b:0002 Linux Foundation 2.0 root hub
    MaxPower                0mA
Bus 002 Device 001: ID 1d6b:0003 Linux Foundation 3.0 root hub
    MaxPower                0mA
Bus 001 Device 003: ID 05ac:12a8 Apple, Inc. iPhone 5/5C/5S/6/SE
    MaxPower              500mA
    MaxPower              500mA
    MaxPower              500mA
    MaxPower              500mA
can't get debug descriptor: Resource temporarily unavailable
Couldn't open device, some information will be missing
  (Bus Powered)
Bus 001 Device 002: ID 8087:0a2b Intel Corp. Bluetooth wireless interface
    MaxPower              100mA
Couldn't open device, some information will be missing
Bus 001 Device 001: ID 1d6b:0002 Linux Foundation 2.0 root hub
    MaxPower                0mA
```

Comment: I have that phone here and it is not a particularly fast charging phone (common for phones of several years ago). But it charges normally from my "always on" USB port and there is no need to change the default power level of the port. Your expectation may be a bit high.

Comment: I've been using this phone since 2.5 years. When plugged in at a charger with 5V and 2A it charges way faster then with only 0.5A. The problem is the laptop/linux and not the phone itself.